# How to cancel a handler before time in Android code?

Tags: android, android-handler

I create 1 minute delayed timer to shutdown service if it's not completed. Looks like this:

```
private Handler timeoutHandler = new Handler();
```

inside onCreate()

```
timeoutHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "timeoutHandler:run");

                DBLog.InsertMessage(getApplicationContext(), "Unable to get fix in 1 minute");
                finalizeService();
            }
        }, 60 * 1000);
```

If I get job accomplished before this 1 minute - I would like to get this delayed thing cancelled but not sure how.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You can't really do it with an anonymous Runnable. How about saving the Runnable to a named variable?

```
Runnable finalizer = new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "timeoutHandler:run");

            DBLog.InsertMessage(getApplicationContext(), "Unable to get fix in 1 minute");
            finalizeService();
        }
    };
timeoutHandler.postDelayed(finalizer, 60 * 1000);

...

// Cancel the runnable
timeoutHandler.removeCallbacks(finalizer);
```

Comment: tiemoutHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null); to remove all callbacks to handle an anonymous Runnable. (as mentioned in AbdelHady answer)

Comment: That's dandy as long as you don't mind removing ALL callbacks, not just this one. OP asked about removing a particular callback.

Answer (score 15):

If you don't want to keep a reference of the runnable, you could simply call:

```
timeoutHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
```

[The official documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#removeCallbacksAndMessages(java.lang.Object)) says:

> ... If token is null, all callbacks and messages will be removed.

Answer (score 10):

You might want to replace use of `postDelayed` with use of `sendMessageDelayed` like so:

```
private Handler timeoutHandler = new Handler(){
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg)
    {
            switch (msg.what){
        case 1:
            ((Runnable)msg.obj).run();
            break;
        }
    }
};
```

Then post a Message:

```
Message m = Message.obtain();
m.what = 1;
m.obj = new Runnable(){
            public void run()
            {
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "timeoutHandler:run");

                DBLog.InsertMessage(getApplicationContext(), "Unable to get fix in 1 minute");
                finalizeService();
            }
        };
timeoutHandler.sendMessageDelayed(m, 60 * 1000);
```

and then cancel:

```
timeoutHandler.removeMessages(1);
```

No tracking of the runnable necessary.

Answer (score 2):

> If I get job accomplished before this 1 minute - I would like to get this delayed thing cancelled but not sure how.

Use [`Handler.removeCallbacks(yourRunnable)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#removeCallbacks%28java.lang.Runnable%29).