# Stop handler.postDelayed()

Tags: android, handler, android-handler, postdelayed

I call multiple Handlers by new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable().....
How can I stop it when I click on back?

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnClickListener {

    private Button btn;
    private Handler handler;
    private Runnable myRunnable;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.trainingsstart);
        btn.setOnClickListener(this);   
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Handler handler =  new Handler();
        Runnable myRunnable = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                // Things to be done
            }
        };

        handler.postDelayed(myRunnable, 3000);
    }

    @Override 
    public void onBackPressed() { 
        super.onBackPressed();
        handler.removeCallbacks(myRunnable);
    }   
}
```

I have the problem that my Handlers haven't a name like "myHandler". How can I handle it?

Thanks for help!

Now I got these error:

```
03-28 17:47:03.662: E/AndroidRuntime(1961): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-28 17:47:03.662: E/AndroidRuntime(1961): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-28 17:47:03.662: E/AndroidRuntime(1961):     at de.basti12354.tage.uebungen.Tag1.onBackPressed(Tag1.java:120)
03-28 17:47:03.662: E/AndroidRuntime(1961):     at android.app.Activity.onKeyUp(Activity.java:2159)
03-28 17:47:03.662: E/AndroidRuntime(1961):     at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:2647)
03-28 17:47:03.662: E/AndroidRuntime(1961):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:2389)
03-28 17:47:03.662: E/AndroidRuntime(1961):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1860)
03-28 17:47:03.662: E/AndroidRuntime(1961):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processKeyEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3791)
03-28 17:47:03.662: E/AndroidRuntime(1961):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:3774)
03-28 17:47:03.662: E/AndroidRuntime(1961):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3379)
03-28 17:47:03.662: E/AndroidRuntime(1961):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3429)
03-28 17:47:03.662: E/AndroidRuntime(1961):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3398)
03-28 17:47:03.662: E/AndroidRuntime(1961):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3483)
03-28 17:47:03.662: E/AndroidRuntime(1961):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3406)
03-28 17:47:03.662: E/AndroidRuntime(1961):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3540)
03-28 17:47:03.662: E/AndroidRuntime(1961):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3379)
03-28 17:47:03.662: E/AndroidRuntime(1961):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3429)
03-28 17:47:03.662: E/AndroidRuntime(1961):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3398)
03-28 17:47:03.662: E/AndroidRuntime(1961):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3406)
03-28 17:47:03.662: E/AndroidRuntime(1961):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3379)
03-28 17:47:03.662: E/AndroidRuntime(1961):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3429)
03-28 17:47:03.662: E/AndroidRuntime(1961):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3398)
03-28 17:47:03.662: E/AndroidRuntime(1961):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3516)
03-28 17:47:03.662: E/AndroidRuntime(1961):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ImeInputStage.onFinishedInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3666)
03-28 17:47:03.662: E/AndroidRuntime(1961):     at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$PendingEvent.run(InputMethodManager.java:1982)
03-28 17:47:03.662: E/AndroidRuntime(1961):     at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.invokeFinishedInputEventCallback(InputMethodManager.java:1698)
03-28 17:47:03.662: E/AndroidRuntime(1961):     at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.finishedInputEvent(InputMethodManager.java:1689)
03-28 17:47:03.662: E/AndroidRuntime(1961):     at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$ImeInputEventSender.onInputEventFinished(InputMethodManager.java:1959)
03-28 17:47:03.662: E/AndroidRuntime(1961):     at android.view.InputEventSender.dispatchInputEventFinished(InputEventSender.java:141)
03-28 17:47:03.662: E/AndroidRuntime(1961):     at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
03-28 17:47:03.662: E/AndroidRuntime(1961):     at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:132)
03-28 17:47:03.662: E/AndroidRuntime(1961):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:124)
03-28 17:47:03.662: E/AndroidRuntime(1961):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
03-28 17:47:03.662: E/AndroidRuntime(1961):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-28 17:47:03.662: E/AndroidRuntime(1961):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
03-28 17:47:03.662: E/AndroidRuntime(1961):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
03-28 17:47:03.662: E/AndroidRuntime(1961):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
03-28 17:47:03.662: E/AndroidRuntime(1961):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 252, accepted):

You can use:

```
 Handler handler = new Handler()
 handler.postDelayed(new Runnable())
```

Or you can use:

```
 handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
```

**Docs**

> public final void removeCallbacksAndMessages (Object token)
>
> Added in API level 1 Remove any pending posts of callbacks and sent
>   messages whose obj is token. If token is null, all callbacks and
>   messages will be removed.

Or you could also do like the following:

```
Handler handler =  new Handler()
Runnable myRunnable = new Runnable() {
public void run() {
    // do something
}
};
handler.postDelayed(myRunnable,zeit_dauer2);
```

Then:

```
handler.removeCallbacks(myRunnable);
```

**Docs**

> public final void removeCallbacks (Runnable r)
>
> Added in API level 1 Remove any pending posts of Runnable r that are
>   in the message queue.
>
> public final void removeCallbacks (Runnable r, Object token)

**Edit:**

Change this:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Handler handler =  new Handler();
    Runnable myRunnable = new Runnable() {
```

To:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    handler = new Handler();
    myRunnable = new Runnable() { /* ... */}
```

Because you have the below. Declared before `onCreate` but you re-declared and then initialized it in `onClick` leading to a NPE.

```
Handler handler; // declared before onCreate
Runnable myRunnable;
```

Comment: Have add the handler.removeCallbacks(myRunnable); to my onBackPressed() is that right?

Comment: @user3433232 use it you want to stop the run

Comment: Can you please look at my code, I try to use your help´, but now I got the errors, you can see at my post.

Comment: @user3433232 check the edit. Your Handler was null. You re -declared it in onClick leading to NPE

Comment: I am working on API 16 and handler.removeCallbacks(runnable) doesn't work. But  handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null); works thanks

Comment: Thanks ! In my case following code works perfectly.`handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);` I have put that code in fragment's `onPause()` method and in `onDestroy()` method.

Answer (score 23):

this may be old, but for those looking for answer you can use this...

```
public void stopHandler() {
   handler.removeMessages(0);
}
```

cheers

Answer (score 21):

You can define a boolean and change it to false when you want to stop handler. Like this..

```
boolean stop = false;

handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {

        //do your work here..

        if (!stop) {
            handler.postDelayed(this, delay);
        }
    }
}, delay);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
  Boolean condition=false;  //Instance variable declaration.

 //-----------------Inside oncreate--------------------------------------------------- 
  start =(Button)findViewById(R.id.id_start);
        start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                starthandler();

                if(condition=true)
                {
                    condition=false;
                }


            }
        });

        stop=(Button) findViewById(R.id.id_stoplocatingsmartplug);

        stop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                stophandler();

            }
        });


    }

//-----------------Inside oncreate---------------------------------------------------

 public void starthandler()
    {

        handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {


                if(!condition)
                {
                    //Do something after 100ms 


                }

            }
        }, 5000);

    }


    public void stophandler()
    {
        condition=true;
    }
```

Comment: Please explain why this piece of code answers the question.

Comment: Assume u have 2 Button in XML start and Stop.                                       
 This code shows the demo of how the handler can be started withe the click of start button and can be stopped by stop button.

Comment: It works but the runnable still runs in the background.

Answer (score 1):

**Explanation:**

Declaring the specific handler before 'onCreate' is necessary. If it is declared inside 'onCreate', they are not sharing the same declaration and thus cannot be identified. This is the problem that the author faced. He has accidentally declared the specific handler inside 'onCreate'.

**Solution:**

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnClickListener {

    private Button btn;
    private Handler handler;
    private Runnable myRunnable;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.trainingsstart);
        btn.setOnClickListener(this);   
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        handler =  new Handler();
        myRunnable = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                // Things to be done
            }
        };

        handler.postDelayed(myRunnable, 3000);
    }

    @Override 
    public void onBackPressed() { 
        super.onBackPressed();
        handler.removeMessages(0);
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best option is to use a boolean as a flag like that, use boolean in onPause & onResume

```
TIME_OUT = 45000;

//add this boolean
boolean run =true;

new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            //run this method only when run is true
             if(run==true){

                //your code
               }

        }
    }, TIME_OUT);

         //change values in onPause
          run=false;
```