# Back Button Does Not Stop Handler

Tags: android

I have an activity that runs the following:

```
    private void loop() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() { 
            public void run() { 

            DBListern(); 
            handler.postDelayed(this, 5000);
        }
    }, 5000); 

}
```

I would like to cancel this handle on back button:

```
    public boolean onBackPress(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)  {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {

        handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);

        return true;

    }

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);

}
```

The handler is still running after back button is pressed, how can I stop it?

Comment: Is this post duplicated? (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22718951/stop-handler-postdelay)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all the right name of the method you are looking for is `onBackPressed()`. So your code is simply not called by framework. Try

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);

    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to do this way:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(mHandler!=null){
        mHandler.removeCallbacks(mRunnable);
    }
    super.onBackPressed();        
}
```

**Reason:** You need to manually remove callback of `Runnable` from `Handler` onBackPress.

Hope this would help you.

Answer (score 0):

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG =  MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    loop();
}

private void loop() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

           Log.i(TAG,"run");
            handler.postDelayed(this, 5000);
        }
    }, 5000);

}

Handler handler = new Handler();

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
}
```

}

this works for me.

Answer (score -1):

For removed handler messeges, you need set not null in method parametrs. Its Must bee lenk on object , or message type, what do yo like to remove. And why you made this chek
`if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {`

its realy nesesary?

Comment: "If token is null, all callbacks and messages will be removed." https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#removeCallbacksAndMessages(java.lang.Object)