# How stop and start postDelayed?

Tags: java, android

What can I do to create buttons of start and stop for this function?

```
final Handler ha=new Handler();
ha.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        //call function

        ha.postDelayed(this, 10000);
    }
}, 10000);
```

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22718951/stop-handler-postdelay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a flag to check for start/stop status before posting to the handler again. Note: This isn't how I would do it though, I would use a `ScheduledExecutorService`.

```
private boolean isRunning = false;
private Handler ha = new Handler();

private void start() {
    isRunning = true;
    ha.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            //call function

            if (isRunning) {
                ha.postDelayed(this, 10000);
            }
        }
    }, 10000);
}

private void stop() {
    isRunning = false;
    ha.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
}
```