# Handler not getting cancelled

Tags: android, android-activity, android-handler

I have created a handler in my app. The functionality of this handler is that if it doesn't detect any user input for 15 seconds(touch,drag etc) it will launch a new activity.
Here is the code for the same.

```
public void startHandler(long duration) {
    if (handler != null) {
        handler.postDelayed(r, duration);
        Log.d("handler", "inside if");
    } else {
        Log.d("handler", "inside else");
        handler = new Handler();
        r = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                Log.d("handler", "handler running");
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityProducts.this, ActivityVideo.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        };
        handler.postDelayed(r, duration);
    }
}
```

Here the duration is dynamic and is fetched from the server.

Below is the code to stop handler.

```
public void stopHandler() {
    if (handler != null) {
        handler.removeCallbacks(r);
        handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
        handler = null;
    }
}
```

And below is the code for starting handler

```
@Override
public void onUserInteraction() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onUserInteraction();
    Log.d("user", "interacted");
    //stop first and then start
    if (duration != 0) {
        stopHandler();
        startHandler(duration);
    }
}
```

I am stopping the handler in all methods **onPause,onStop and onDestroy**. But the problem is that if I navigate to any other activity from this activity the start handler code still executes and takes me to the Video Activity.

So what is the proper way of stopping the handler?

Comment: Perhaps you are winding up with multiple `Handler` instances somehow. Since `postDelayed()` and `removeCallbacks()` are both on `View`, perhaps you could try using some existing `View` in your layout, rather than creating a `Handler`.

Comment: Can you include the code where you are calling `stopHandler()` when leaving the activity?

Comment: @waqaslam I have mentioned that. I am calling stop handler method in onPause,onStop,onDestroy

Comment: @CommonsWare sir can you give an example of what you are trying to say ? How to use existing views ?

Comment: [This sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/v8.11/Threads/PostDelayed) demonstrates using `postDelayed()` and `removeCallbacks()` without a `Handler`.

Comment: @CommonsWare so can I use any view from my activity's layout or it has to be the parent layout ?

Comment: I do not know what "the parent layout" means. AFAIK, any `View` should work for `postDelayed()` and `removeCallbacks()`.

Comment: Okay. By parent layout I meant to say the root element of the layout file like relative or linear layout

Comment: VivekMishra It is the root layout which @Commonsware has mentioned. i.e. 'root=findViewById(android.R.id.content);'

Comment: In that sample, I happen to use the `android.R.id.content` `View`, but that is not required.

Comment: I tried with the approach mentioned in the link but the toast fired immediately. How can I switch to the activity after the time defined in post Delayed ?

Comment: possible of dublicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22718951/stop-handler-postdelay

Comment: @AmjadKhan Before marking duplicate please read the content of the question too. I am already doing everything mentioned in that link