# How to change/reset handler post delayed time?

Tags: android, handler, postdelayed

I'm using `postDelayed` method of the `Handler` in order to perform an action after certain amount of time:

```
private static int time_to_wait = 2000;

Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
    // Make Action
  }
}, time_to_wait);
```

now in the middle of the waiting time i want to change the value of the remaining milliseconds due to some processing results, let's say it now waited **1000 ms** and i want to make it begins to count from **2000** again, So, i set the `time_to_wait` value to 2000 but it doesn't take that in count as it only takes the var value **(2000)** and just waits that time regardless changing the `time_to_wait` value to any other value.

Comment: You need to cancel and repost the runnable I believe.

[StackOverflow][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7407242/how-to-cancel-handler-postdelayed

Comment: @Kaediil that won't be so efficient in my case

Comment: `int` is a primitive type and is passed by value - the value is copied, and is not connected with original primitive variable anyhow. If you pass `int` variable to some method, and then try to change that variable somewhere else (outside that method), the changes to the variable will not be reflected in this method, as it possesses it's own copy of variable

Comment: @Drew well, Great, now if I want to do what i explained, do you have any idea how ?

Comment: @MuhammedRefaat store a reference to your Runnable, declaring it as `Runnable r = new Runnable(...);`. You will post it like: `handler.postDelayed(r, time_to_wait);`. You could cancel it in the meantime by calling `handler.removeCallbacks(r);`. And then post it again, depending on your app's logic. Hope that helps.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46403060/restart-a-handler-postdelayed-in-java/51984070#51984070) could be helpful for you.

Comment: @OlgaKonoreva yeah it's the same technique I used in the answer here, something else, I believe the question you mentioned as mine is duplicate of should be the one that is duplicate for mine, as it has been asked after mine by more than three years :D

Comment: @MuhammedRefaat Yeap, you are right :) I'm removing my flag.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

this can be achieved by easily create a runnable that will be displayed by the handler, then creating the handler as static member, finally when you want to stop it just remove the callback of your created runnable, and if you want to restart it you have to remove the callback and assign it again:

```
Runnable myRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // your code here
    }
};

public static Handler myHandler = new Handler();
private static final int TIME_TO_WAIT = 2000;

public void start() {
    myHandler.postDelayed(myRunnable, TIME_TO_WAIT);
}

public void stop() {
    myHandler.removeCallbacks(myRunnable);
}

public void restart() {
    myHandler.removeCallbacks(myRunnable);
    myHandler.postDelayed(myRunnable, TIME_TO_WAIT);
}
```

Comment: when using `removeCallbacks` what will happen if `myRunnable` wasn't running. Will the application crash?

Comment: @MohamadMousheimish I think it will not, as if the runnable is not running it will do nothing, but I'm just guessing and I'm not pretty sure about that, better to surround it with try-catch block or make a check before running it

Answer (score 0):

you can just try

```
handler.removeMessage(what)
handler.sendMessageDelayed(time_to_wait + INTERVER);
```

every time you need first remove message and then send a new message.

Answer (score 0):

KOTLIN VERSION:   (#Muhammed Refaat's Answer):

```
var myHandler = Handler()
private val TIME_TO_WAIT: Long = 2000

var myRunnable = Runnable {
    // your code here
}

fun start() {
    myHandler.postDelayed(myRunnable, TIME_TO_WAIT)
}

fun stop() {
    myHandler.removeCallbacks(myRunnable)
}

fun restart() {
    stop()
    start()
}
```