# Restart a handler.postDelayed in Java

Tags: java, android, android-handler

```
@Override
public void onUserInteraction() {
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable () {
        public void run() {
            finish();
        }
    }, 5000);
    handler.removeCallbacks(null);
}
```

I am trying to run the handler when the OnCreate method is called. I would then like to cancel the handler and call it again (restart the handler) when I receive user interaction.

How would I do this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Check https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#removeCallbacks(java.lang.Runnable)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a boolean object, example:

```
@Override
public void onUserInteraction() {
    isStarted = true;
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable () {
        public void run() {
          if(isStarted){
            finish();
            }
         }
    }, 5000);
```

}

or you can make something like this:

```
Runnable myRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        finish();
    }
};

public static Handler myHandler = new Handler();
private static final int TIME_TO_WAIT = 5000;

@Override
public void onUserInteraction() {
    restart();
}

public void start() {
    myHandler.postDelayed(myRunnable, TIME_TO_WAIT);
}

public void stop() {
    myHandler.removeCallbacks(myRunnable);
}

public void restart() {
    myHandler.removeCallbacks(myRunnable);
    myHandler.postDelayed(myRunnable, TIME_TO_WAIT);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This works for triggering the handler code but then how would i cancel it and call it again once i get another user interaction? Essentially I would like to close the app 5 seconds after I receive a user interact ion, but if there is another interaction before the 5 seconds then the timer will restart

Comment: I edit answer for you

Comment: Thankyou! (But there is no need for start or stop for my purpose so i just used restart)

Answer (score 2):

Store the runnable and handler in a field and reuse them

```
Handler handler;
Runnable runnable = new Runnable () {
    public void run() {
        finish();
    }
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(runnable, 5000);
}

@Override
public void onUserInteraction() {
    handler.removeCallbacks(null);
    handler.postDelayed(runnable, 5000);
}
```

Comment: This partially works, however the userinteraction does not cancel the handler which is called oncreate. This means the app closes after 5 seconds even if the user is interacting with the app

Comment: @hinch I copied your call. Try with `handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);`

Answer (score 0):

Create a handler and keep its reference as global variable

```
private Runnable runnable;
private Handler newHandler;

newHandler = new Handler();
runnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            //update UI
            newHandler.postDelayed(runnable,100);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
};
newHandler.post(runnable);
```

And on user Interaction

```
@Override
public void onUserInteraction() {
    super.onUserInteraction();
   newHandler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
    //Do some task
    if(//task done){
     newHandler.postDelayed(runnable,100);
     }
}
```

Comment: It says newHandler and runnable are not assigned

Comment: where you are getting that error?in the beginning or inside userinteration method?

Comment: its working code..it should work fine,any ways updated code..check now

Answer (score 0):

It was not work for me until I used Handler's `removeCallbacksAndMessages(Object token)` method.

On kotlin

```
private var restartingHandler = Handler()
private var runnable: () -> Unit = {}

fun start() {
    restartingHandler.postDelayed(runnable, 5000L)
}

fun restart() {
    restartingHandler.removeCallbacks(runnable)
    restartingHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null)

    restartingHandler.postDelayed(runnable, 5000L)
}

fun stop() {
    restartingHandler.removeCallbacks(runnable)
    restartingHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null)
}
```

Comment: since you use kotlin check https://stackoverflow.com/q/62405834/2736039